# Линейная последовательность действий

Tags: c#

Нужно, чтобы функции выполнялись в линейной последовательности. Но с разными интервалами.

Сейчас я делаю так

```
    delay((myDelegate)fun1, 2);
    delay((myDelegate)fun2, 5);

    delay((myDelegate)fun3, 8);
    delay((myDelegate)fun4, 10);
    delay((myDelegate)fun5, 15);

    delay((myDelegate)fun6, 20);


private void delay(myDelegate fun, int time)
{
    var _delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    int minute_rnd = time;
    _delayTimer.Interval = minute_rnd * 1000;
    _delayTimer.AutoReset = false;
    _delayTimer.Elapsed += (s, args) => fun();
    _delayTimer.Start();
}
```

Но это очень корявая реализация, так как иногда залипает, и два подряд срабатывает и последовательность сбивается.

Как это можно стабильно реализовать?

Comment: Какой версией .NET Framework пользуетесь?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ @nzeemin правильный, но если вам нужна ещё и асинхронность, делайте так:

```
async Task ExecuteAll()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    fun1();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    fun2();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    fun3();
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    fun4();
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    fun5();
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    fun6();
}
```

Заметьте, что `fun1` и остальные должны быть достаточно быстрыми, иначе их стоит тоже сделать асинхронными.

Answer (score 4):

Если последовательность линейная, то зачем вообще таймер?

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
fun1();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
fun2();
```

...

Comment: Sleep - тормозит отклик программы. Она как бы зависает. Так не пойдет.